# Interface error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

In my program, when I call updateNextPortNum method in following piece of code, why here has an error， said: "Multiple markers at this line
               - router cannot be resolved
               - newRouterIp cannot be resolved to a variable"

```
else if (operType.equals("3")){
            System.out.println("Inpur router number: ");
            String routerNum = br.readLine();

            error ==> rm.updateNextPortNum(routerNum, newRouterIp, newPortNum);
        }
```

the called function in  class RouterManage:

```
class RouterManage {
    private ArrayList al = null;

    public RouterManage() {
        al = new ArrayList();
    }

    // add Router
    public void addRouter(Router router) {
        al.add(router);
    }

    // show information of Router
    public void showInfo(String routerNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            // take Router object out
            Router router = (Router) al.get(i);

            if (router.getRouterNum().equals(routerNum)) {
                System.out.println("Find this router, info of its: ");
                System.out.println("Router num: " + routerNum);
                System.out.println("Router IP: " + router.getRouterIp());
                System.out.println("Next Router PortNum: " + router.getNextPortNum());
            }
        }
    }

    // show information of Router
    public void showAllInfo(String routerNum, String routerIp, int nextPortNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {

            Router router = (Router) al.get(i);

            System.out.println("All router information: ");
            System.out.println("Router num: " + routerNum);
            System.out.println("Router IP: " + router.getRouterIp());
            System.out.println("Next Router PortNum: " + router.getNextPortNum());
        }
    }

    // change next port num
    public void updateNextPortNum(String routerNum, String newRouterIp, int newPortNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            Router router = (Router) al.get(i);

            if (router.getRouterNum().equals(routerNum)) {
                // change router's ip
                router.setRouterIp(newRouterIp);
                // change router port number
                router.setNextPortNum(newPortNum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just try to write a simple interface to achieve the selection function.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Because `router` and `newRouterIp` are not in scope there.  Where/how are those variables declared?

Comment: maybe your router & newRouterIp doesnt exist . try to declare it first. `String router;` & `String newRouterIp;` inside your scope. or post your code where you declared it.

Comment: @azurefrog I notice that, renew the program above, problem still not be unsolved.

Comment: @Secondo renew the code, error still exists there.

Comment: put the code where error exist. i doubt about the variable `newRouterIp` where do you declare you newRouterIp ? . there are no problem on your `RouterManage` class.

Comment: @Secondo in the first part of code: error ==> rm.updateNextPortNum(routerNum, newRouterIp, newPortNum);

Comment: yah i know sir :) i want the whole code of that class. i want to know where do you create the variable `newRouterIp`. `newRouterIp cannot be resolved to a variable` it means that the `newRouterIp` is not a variable or doesnt exist.

Comment: it may be redundant just want to summarize my comments :)) .  You are getting that compilation error because `newRouterIp` doesnt exist/declared ( i assumed ).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a String and pass to the method updateNextPortNum. Even if the parameter and argument have the same name in the same file, scoping rules mean they are different variables. In the scope of the conditional check blocks, create a string or assign/do

```
String newRouterId = "192.168.1.1";
```

Answer (score 0):

in following code:

```
System.out.println("Inpur router number: ");
String routerNum = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Input new router IP: ");
String newRouterIp = br.readLine();
System.out.println("Input new port number: ");
int newPortNum = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

rm.updateNextPortNum(routerNum, newRouterIp, newPortNum);
```

the "newRouterIp and newPortNum" need be read in BufferedReader.

What a silly mistake :D

Comment: see told you :) XD you need to create a newRouterIp variable first before using it.

Answer (score 0):

It was in ArrayList, However, considering about the security, I recode this in HashTable:

```
//delete router
public void delRouter(String routerNum){    

    Router router = (Router)ht.get(routerNum);  

    if(router.getRouterNum().equals(routerNum)){
        // delete object
        //al.remove(i);
        ht.remove(routerNum);
    }
}
```